# MouseMove Event in variable

Tags: c#

I pass my object into another class as a variable. My object has a mousemove event. Is it possible to store this event to be reassigned later?

eg

```
// Class 1     
private void mainDisplay_mousemove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
 ...
 ...
}

void FunctionInClass1()
{
   OverlayManager.Instance.CallAnotherClass(mainDisplay);

}

//Class 2

internal void ConfigureManager(Map mainDisplay)
{
   // how do I save the mousemove event?
   var handle = mainDisplay.MouseMove
}
```

To explain more. In class1 I have a object called mainDisplay which is a map component. I have mousemove/ mouseup/ mousedown events on the map where the user can draw/ drag symbols on the map. Now class 2 is overlays layer which means that there are different kinds of symbols which the user can draw using his mouse. Basically the map has two different sets of mouse events and I want to store these and assign them when required

Comment: I'm trying to understand the flow of this logic... couldn't you just call the function from within the mousemove?

Comment: What do you mean with _"... **store** this event to be **reassigned** later..."_? If you mean: "save underlying (multicast) delegate, replace it with a new one and then restore _old_ one when you're done" then no, you can't. It's why we have `event` instead of _plain_ `delegate`. Of course you can create your own event, move this _logic_ in your `Control` and forward `MouseMove` event to your `ReplaceableMouseMove` event.

Comment: outside the class where it is defined events can only use the `+=` and `-=` operators.  Maybe you'd do better explaining what you are trying to accomplish rather than focusing down on this specific possible implementation.